# "that you find it a helpful suggestion" vs "that you found it a helpful suggestion"

Tags: past-simple, present-simple

Suppose that you give a suggestion in comment to someone and he says that your comment was helpful.

Is it wrong to say

> I am glad that you find it a helpful suggestion.

I know I can use the past tense "found", but I am curious to know how do you read it if the tense is present.

I feel that using the present simple will imply a sense of politeness or formality. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it helped refers to some event that already occurred, so it has to be past tense.

> I am glad that you **found** it (to be) a helpful suggestion.

To make it present tense, if in-progress -

> I am glad that you **are finding** it (to be) a helpful suggestion.

or just a suggestion in the present (the suggestion hasn't been tried yet) -

> **I will be glad if you find it** (to be) a helpful suggestion.

But really your gladness can only occur after the fact, so in your context it needs to be past tense.